# Writing custom intrinsic in LLVM

Tags: llvm, intrinsics, llvm-c++-api

I'm trying to create a custom intrinsic in LLVM. I've already read the guide here: https://llvm.org/docs/ExtendingLLVM.html, but it's quite poor, so I have several questions.

First of all, I get that I should write the intrinsic entry in *.td file, but I don't understand where exactly should I write instructions which intrinsic will be raplaced with.

Secondly, I found tablegen language references but it looks like intrinsic's definition has the specific syntaxys and I can't find its references.

Finslly, after adding the intrinsic and code-generator support for it, can I just insert it through my custom pass with IRBuilder?

Thanks to everyone.

Comment: When and where the intrinsic is lowered is up to you, but you can start with `IntrinsicLowering` class: https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1IntrinsicLowering.html

Comment: "after adding the intrinsic and code-generator support for it, can I just insert it through my custom pass with IRBuilder?"
Intrinsics are calls to functions whose names start with "llvm.". You'd use the IRBuilder to insert a call to that function. You'll need to get the function by knowing its name and type and creating a declaration for it.